# Don't we have single sign-on for all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, login

I would like to use many sites in the Stack Exchange network, but I need to login to each site separately. Though it's easy, can't we solve this problem? I know each site has a different url :( but is there any way?

Answer (score 4):

As long as you have an account on the site, you will be signed on automatically. [Global Logins](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) has been available since September. The rules are:

> - You have recently logged in to any Stack Exchange network site

- You hold an existing account on the target site you’re navigating to
- You are using the same OpenID credentials

Comment: You also need to be using an HTML5-compatible browser (at least local storage), which is possibly the reason it's not working for the OP

Comment: It appears to be working inconsistently for me. Sometimes my name is at the top of the screen, yet it acts like I'm not logged in. Sometimes after logging in I can go to another site and function normally, sometimes I cannot.

Comment: Note: this feature is broken, at least for me. I forgot my password a while ago but I was still logged in on stackoverflow. navigating from stackoverflow to arqade did not log me in on arqade. Even pressing the login button there didn't work. But I was still logged in to stackoverflow after navigating back.